# Sitecore 7 Index Configuration Issue

Tags: xml, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

We have done a Sitecore upgrade into 7.0 rev.131127 (7.0 Update-3).
We have created a separate config file for each index and each index has some custom fields as well. Following is the structure of an config file.

```
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <DefaultIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>
          <Analyzer ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/analyzer" />
          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
            <field fieldName="word-search" storageType="NO" indexType="UN_TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO">LowerCaseTrimmedField, Project</field>
          <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
            <!--Notes Template-->
            <note>{21176496-CE68-48A0-860F-BB73CFB52D65}</note>
          </include>
          <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Converters.LuceneIndexFieldStorageValueFormatter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          </indexFieldStorageValueFormatter>
          <indexDocumentPropertyMapper type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.DefaultLuceneDocumentTypeMapper, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
          <fieldReaders type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReaderMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          </fieldReaders>
        </DefaultIndexConfiguration>
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="IndexName" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
            <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/intervalAsyncCore" />
            </strategies>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>core</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/Root</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

However when an index is rebuilt it merges custom fields and include templates from from other indices into that index. Appreciate your input regarding this.

Hi TwentyGotoTen,
as you have suggested here is the merged contentsearch node from /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx file. I removed some of the content for convienience. I can see that all default configurations from config files are merged into a single section and this is the reason behind this weird behavior. What could be done to stop this from happening ?

```
    <contentSearch patch:source="Index1.config">
    <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
      <DefaultIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>
        <Analyzer ref="contentSearch/configuration/defaultIndexConfiguration/analyzer"/>
        <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
          All included templates in config files
        </include>
        <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
          All custom fields in config files
        </fields>
        <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Converters.LuceneIndexFieldStorageValueFormatter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        </indexFieldStorageValueFormatter>
        <indexDocumentPropertyMapper type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.DefaultLuceneDocumentTypeMapper, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider"/>
        <fieldReaders type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReaderMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        </fieldReaders>
        <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch" patch:source="Index1.config">
        </fieldMap>
        <analyzer type="AllClassifieds.Web.extensions.indexing.Analysers.ClassifiedContentAnalyser" patch:source="Index1.config"/>

        <exclude hint="list:ExcludeTemplate" patch:source="Index1.config">
          All excluded templates in config files
        </exclude>
      </DefaultIndexConfiguration>
      <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
        <index id="Index1" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
          <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
          <!--
 This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id 
-->
          <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)"/>
          <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
            <!--
 NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order 
-->
            <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync"/>
          </strategies>
          <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
            <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <Database>web</Database>
              <Root>/sitecore/Path</Root>
            </crawler>
          </locations>
        </index>
        <index id="Index2" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" patch:source="Index1.config">
          <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
          <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
          <!--
 This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id 
-->
          <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)"/>
          <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
            <!--
 NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order 
-->
            <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/intervalAsyncMaster"/>
          </strategies>
          <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
            <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <Database>master</Database>
              <Root>/sitecore/Path</Root>
            </crawler>
          </locations>
        </index>
      </indexes>
      <defaultIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config">

      </defaultIndexConfiguration>
    </configuration>
    <!--
 INDEXING STRATEGIES 
           Here is a list of the different indexing strategies that you can use. You can also combine these strategies to achieve what you want.

-->
    <indexUpdateStrategies patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config">

    </indexUpdateStrategies>
    <databasePropertyStore type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexDatabasePropertyStore, Sitecore.ContentSearch" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config">
      <Key>$(1)</Key>
      <Database>core</Database>
    </databasePropertyStore>
  </contentSearch>
```

Comment: Can you supply the `contentSearch` node from your merged web.config file? Available at `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`

Comment: May be a good idea to submit a ticket to Sitecore Support

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a problem with the structure of your include files.

Sitecore have just produced a  document on Sitecore config patching which illustrates all the features and constraints of the includes patching facilities.

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Include%20File%20Patching%20Facilities.aspx

There is also a wealth of helpful information on the subject elsewhere:

https://www.google.com/?q=sitecore+includes#q=sitecore+includes

I suggest that you review these resources and make sure that your include files are setup correctly. As you have seen, `showconfig.aspx` is a valuable tool in debugging config issues, but if you are still having trouble then as [Mark Ursino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134360/mark-ursino) suggests, you should raise a ticket with Sitecore Support.